# Meaning of 「この調子で頑張って」

Tags: translation, meaning

**Context**

I wrote and submitted text in Japanese to be corrected, and received a correction from an acquaintance followed by 「この調子で頑張って」.

**Question**

I understand 調子【ちょうし】 to be something like "condition" or "state of affairs", but I am not sure I understand this sentence clearly.

Is it perhaps something like "Keep going at this pace!" or "Keep it up!"?

What is 調子 referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've pretty much got it.

調子 refers to the pace, so it translates literally to something like "keep going at this pace". You could translate it less literally to things like "keep it up" or "keep up the good work".

Either way, it's definitely a statement of encouragement.

Answer (score 3):

To complete Blavius' answer, 研究社 新和英大辞典 says for 調子 :

> 3 〔やり方〕 a way; a manner; a style; 〔こつ〕 a knack; a hang.
>
> こういう調子で　in this way [manner]
>
> こういう調子でやってください.　Please do it this way.
>
> 彼はだれに対しても同じような調子で接する.　He acts the same way toward everyone.
>
> 調子を飲み込む　get the hang 《of…》; get [acquire] the knack 《of…》.
>
> その調子, その調子!　That's it. ｜ That's the way. ｜ Keep it up. ｜ That's more like it.
>
> 田舎では万事がこの調子だ.　This is the way things go in the country.
>
> この人, いつもこんな調子なんですよ.　This is the way he always is.

Comment: Thanks! Really helped me better understand the meaning of 調子!